# Tightness of measures on complete metric spaces

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

There are 2 theorems

1. Every probability measure on polish space is tight
2. Let $\mu$ be a borel probability measure on complete separable metric space $X$. Then for any borel set $B \in B(x)$ and for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a compact set $K\subset B$ such that $\mu (K) > 1 - \epsilon$

Both of this theorems require space to be separable, and my question is, what if space won't be separable, then why this theorems doesn't work? I read proofs of both of them, but i can't understand where it will break and why. Especially I'm interested in second theorem

Comment: You have the inequality the wrong way around in $2$ right? For probability measures, as written the inequality is trivial.

Comment: Metric spaces can have very few compact sets. In fact, only finite sets can be compact. Separability is explicitly used in the proof of the second result.

Comment: Yes, the inequality is in the wrong way, thx.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How can i proof that it is will be wrong if space is not separable? If I'm understanding right, there are very few compact sets and they are not enough for every epsilon, but it's doesn't sounds rigorous